# Handling matplotlib.figure.Figure using openCV

Tags: image, opencv, matplotlib, scipy

I am using the following code to find the spectrogram of a signal and save it.

```
spec,freq,t,im = plt.specgram(raw_signal,Fs=100,NFFT=100,noverlap=50)
plt.axis('off')
figure = plt.gcf()
figure.set_size_inches(12, 1)
plt.savefig('spectrogram',bbox_inches = 'tight',pad_inches=0)
```

[image]

But I have multiple spectrograms like this and the end product I need is a concatenation of all these. Right now, what I am doing is, I am saving all these individual images using `plt.savefig()` as earlier and reading them back using `cv2.imread()` and concatenating them. But this process is not very good I think. So is there any other way I can do this without saving it and re-reading it?

One possible idea I have is, somehow converting `matplotlib.figure.Figure` into a format that can be handled by OpenCV (specifically cv2). However, it should also not have white padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the image as an array using [`buffer_rgba`](https://matplotlib.org/api/backend_agg_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg.buffer_rgba) (don't forget to `draw` the image first). Then in OpenCV, you need to convert the image from `RGB` to OpenCV's `BGR` channel ordering.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

raw_signal =  np.random.random(1000)
spec,freq,t,im = plt.specgram(raw_signal,Fs=100,NFFT=100,noverlap=50)
plt.axis('off')
figure = plt.gcf()
figure.set_size_inches(12, 1)
figure.set_dpi(50)

figure.canvas.draw()

b = figure.axes[0].get_window_extent()
img = np.array(figure.canvas.buffer_rgba())
img = img[int(b.y0):int(b.y1),int(b.x0):int(b.x1),:]
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)
cv2.imshow('OpenCV',img)
```

Top: matplotlib, bottom OpenCV:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems like it will work. Let me try

Comment: Thanks, this almost works. But I am still not able to control the white/transparent background around it. Is there anything equivalent to  `bbox_inches = 'tight',pad_inches=0` from savefig?

Comment: Also, I would like to know if there is any way to control the dpi as well?

Comment: please see my updated answer: you can set the dpi and we save just the axes object, not the whole figure

Answer (score 0):

don't save the figure. matplotlib happens to have a convenience function for *displaying* time series data in this way but that's not how you deal with spectrograms. any handling of spectrogram "pictures" is a kludge.

use [`scipy.signal.spectrogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html) to get the actual spectrogram.

Comment: But this way, I will not be able to control white padding. For now, I am doing it during savefig(). And, how will do this for multiple spectrograms and concatenate them all if I am not dealing with them as pictures?